# Logarithmic inequality

Tags: logarithms

Solve the inequality:
$$
\log_8(x^2-4x+3) < 1
$$
$$
\log_8(x^2-4x+3) < \log_8(8)
$$
$$
\log_8(x^2-4x+3) - \log_8(8) <0
$$
$$
\log_8 [(x^2-4x+3)/8] < 0
$$
Thats what I did for the question so far... and I'm confused as to what to do next. Can someone verify this for me?

Comment: What numbers have negative logarithms? Regardless of the base, those numbers are precisely the numbers $y$ such that $0<y<1.$ So now you have a fact about the quantity $(x^2-4x+3)/8,$ in which the logarithm function no longer need appear, although you may have worked harder than you needed to in order to get it.

Answer (score 2):

**A start**: We have $\log_8(x^2-4x+3)\lt 1$ precisely if $0\lt x^2-4x+3\lt 8^1$.

Comment: So I can just factor x^2-4x+3, which is (x-3)(x-1) and x=1,3 are the inequalities?

Comment: For the inequality $0\lt x^2-4x+3$, factoring is useful. The other inequality should be rewritten as $x^2-4x-5\lt 0$. Now work on these for a while, I will not give further detail until there is some evidence of progress. The log is gone, the problem now has a more familiar shape.  If you reach a conclusion, I can tell you whether you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $\log(n)$ is defined only if $n \in (0,\infty)$
$$
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow\quad x^2 - 4x + 3 &\in (0,\infty)\\
\Rightarrow\quad x^2 - 4x + 3 &> 0\\
\Rightarrow (x-3)(x-1) &> 0\\
\end{align}
$$
$$
\boxed{\therefore\quad x \in (-\infty, 1)\cup(3,\infty) 
\quad\text{or}\quad x\in \mathbb R \sim [1,3]}\tag{1}
$$

Now, $\log_b(n) = y \iff n = b^y$,
$$
\begin{align}
\log_8(x^2-4x+3) &< 1\\
\Rightarrow x^2 - 4x + 3 &< 8^1\\
\Rightarrow x^2 - 4x - 5 &< 0\\
\Rightarrow (x+1)(x-5) &< 0
\end{align}
$$
$$
\boxed{\therefore x\in\left(-1,5\right)} \tag{2}
$$

Remember that both $(1)$ and $(2)$ have to be satisfied at the same time.

Now, $(1)\cap(2) \implies x\in(-1,1)\cup(3,5)$

Answer (score 0):

Here's are some steps
$$ \log_8 (x^2-4x+3)\lt 1 $$
$$ 8^{\log_8 (x^2-4x+3)}\lt 8^1 $$
$$ 0\lt x^2-4x+3\lt 8 $$
$$ -8\lt x^2-4x-5\lt 0 $$
$$ -8\lt (x+1)(x-5)\lt 0 $$
Can you take it from here?